# Access session in custom authorize filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I use the `Session["userName"]` in my custom authorize filter?

```
void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{            
    string userName = Session["userName"]; // Shows error "The name 'Session' does not exist in the current context              

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Session` dictionary is available trough:

```
void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{            
    string userName = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["userName"];               

    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```